# How to convert JSON file to data frame using tidyjson package?

Tags: r, json

**I used tidyjson package to convert json file to data frame as following:**

> ```
>  json%>%as.tbl_json%>% spread_values(id = jstring("_id"))%>%
>                  enter_object("courses")%>%
>                  spread_values(course_id = jstring( "course_id"),
>                               created_at = jstring("created_at"),
>                                update_at = jstring("updated_at"),
>                                percentage = jnumber("percentage"),
>                                category = jstring( "category"),
>                                course_length = jnumber( "course_length"),
>                                learn_length = jnumber( "learn_length"))
> ```

**But i got an unexpected result.**

> ```
>          document.id id        course_id created_at update_at percentage category
>    <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr>   
>        1 55aa41af~ NA        NA         NA                NA NA       with 2 more variables: course_length <dbl>, learn_length <dbl>
> ```

**Could you please help me to find where i was wrong ?**
**This is my json file i want to convert:**

> ```
> json <- '{"_id": "55aa41af736773421a000000",   "courses": [{"course_id": "55b1c17152696418a000005b",
> "created_at": "2018-08-13 09:56:00.099000",
> "updated_at": "2015-08-14 13:49:00.545000",
> "percentage": 13.938669852648347,
> "category": "Language",
> "course_length": 2511,
> "learn_length": 350.0}]}'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
require(jsonlite);require(dplyr)
te <- fromJSON(json) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's good for my example above. But when i try this code on a large JSON file about 250MB, it doesn't work well. Why ?

Comment: it is normal that it takes some time, If it is not working at all you can try fromJSON(json) %>% unlist() %>% as.data.frame() . It also depends on the amount of RAM you have, and if you're using 64 or 32-bit R. Check the memory in task manager when R is working, you might see the memory usage skyrocket.

Comment: I also try fromJSON(json)%>% unlist() %>% as.data.frame() , but it doesn't work too. I have 4GB of RAM and 64-bit R. Is it enough for processing my 250 MB Json file ?

Comment: I don't think so, From my experience, Json files are greedy and with 8GB I'm having trouble with 250mb excel files. What happens if you let it run for a while?

Comment: It read not correctly Json file. My Json file has the same format as the example i posted above. But with this code, i just obtained only 2 fields and about 900000 records. When i want to show these records, R automatically starts new session.

Comment: I think it is working well, probably the first column is the name of the field, and the second is the value. The reason why you dont have a nice data frame might be because the json has a complex structure. But all the data should be extracted. try to unlist() before viewing some of the values, with unique(firstcolumn) for example